# Вывести среднею стоимость товаров на странице Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Вывел товары по категориям, нужно вывести их среднею стоимость? смог получить только саму стоимость.

```
            $saleArgs = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'sale',
                    )
                ),
            );
            $sale = new WP_Query($saleArgs); ?>
            <?php if ($sale->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($sale->have_posts()) : $sale->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php wc_get_template_part('content', 'product'); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $sale = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_price', true);
                    echo $salee  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Перед циклом создайте пустой массив.
Внутри цикла записывайте в этот массив все цены нужных товаров.
После цикла сложите элементы массива и поделите на количество.

Бот stackoverflow захотел что бы я добавил немного кода.

```
$arrayPrice = [];
// Тут начало цикла вывода товаров
$arrayPrice[] = (int)$sale;
// Тут заканчивается цикл вывода товаров
$all = array_sum($arrayPrice)/count($arrayPrice);
echo $all;
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).